# Western Digital HDD not getting detected in BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

I have a Western Digital 140GB HDD. It worked fine until a few days ago in my desktop. But today, when I booted it, the boot failed at Verifying DMI pool Data and then it said:

> No System Disk Found , Please insert a system Disk

So I shut the PC down and entered the BIOS. It showed my DVD drive but not my HDD. The WD has Win7 x86 Professional. It has 2 partitions , `C:` and `D:`. The drive is set to IDE in BIOS.
Please help as valuable information is on this drive. My boot order is HDD first.

Comment: The drive is dead. Restore from backups.

Comment: Try reseating the SATA and power cables, use a different SATA cable and port. If nothing changes try running [WD DLG](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=LF2hrr) for DOS. If the software doesn't detect the drive there is probably nothing more you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

first thing to try is setting default values in the BIOS to see if the drive is recognised then. Secondly, check cable for damage and possbly try another one. Thirdly, I'd attemp a BIOS update which you can find from the motherboard vendor.

Additionally, have you access to an external drive caddy which will help to see if the drive can be read from another system..?

Comment: no i havent got an external caddy

Comment: Any luck with resetting bios to default and upgrading to latest version if available..?

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to find out what this cause is, but here a list to begin with

- Make sure connected cables are well connected. If you can, replace the cable to check if it's damaged
- Give the BIOS factory settings a try (reset default)
- Try to boot a live cd (e.g. Ubuntu) and have a look if it sees it
- It could be your MBR or the boot-manager is damaged (or another disk was holding that information), but please check the previous points first
- Have you had another disk in your pc? (implies question above)
- Does your disk make strange "clicking" noises (if yes, could be your disk died)
  -